# React: Infinite loop when using custom hook inside of useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a custom hook to wrap about Notistack (https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack), a library for snackbars.

My hook looks like this:

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useSnackbar as useNotistackSnackbar } from 'notistack';

import { SNACKBAR_TYPES } from '../constants/properties';

const useSnackbar = () => {
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useNotistackSnackbar();

  const showSnackbarVariant = useCallback(
    ({ text, action_text, onActionClick, variant }) =>
      enqueueSnackbar(
        {
          variant,
          text,
          action_text,
          onActionClick,
        },
        { autoHideDuration: action_text && onActionClick ? 9000 : 4000 }
      ),
    [enqueueSnackbar]
  );

  return {
    showSuccessSnackbar: ({ text, action_text, onActionClick }) =>
      showSnackbarVariant({
        variant: SNACKBAR_TYPES.SUCCESS,
        text,
        action_text,
        onActionClick,
      }),
    showErrorSnackbar: ({ text, action_text, onActionClick }) =>
      showSnackbarVariant({
        variant: SNACKBAR_TYPES.ERROR,
        text,
        action_text,
        onActionClick,
      }),
    showWarningSnackbar: ({ text, action_text, onActionClick }) =>
      showSnackbarVariant({
        variant: SNACKBAR_TYPES.WARNING,
        text,
        action_text,
        onActionClick,
      }),
    showDownloadSnackbar: ({ text, action_text, onActionClick }) =>
      showSnackbarVariant({
        variant: SNACKBAR_TYPES.DOWNLOAD,
        text,
        action_text,
        onActionClick,
      }),
    showPlainSnackbar: ({ text, action_text, onActionClick }) =>
      showSnackbarVariant({
        variant: SNACKBAR_TYPES.PLAIN,
        text,
        action_text,
        onActionClick,
      }),
  };
};

export default useSnackbar;
```

I need to use it in 2 places:

1. outside of useEffect (but still within the component)
2. inside of useEffect

However, even if I just add it as just a dependency on useEffect, it causes the infinite loop inside useEffect:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  const { showSuccessSnackbar, showErrorSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  const { mutate: activateConnectedAccount } =
    useCustomHook({
      onSuccess: async () => {
        showSuccessSnackbar({
          text: 'Direct deposit has been enabled.',
        });
      },
      onError: () => {
        showErrorSnackbar({
          text: 'An error occurred. Please double check your bank information.',
        });
      },
    });

  useEffect(
    () => {
      activateConnectedAccount()
      console.log("yooo");
    },
    [
      // showSuccessSnackbar
    ]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      Foobar
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox link:
If you comment in line 30, it will cause the browser to freeze because it keeps running that loop

https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-browser-5vomm?file=/src/MyComponent.js

Comment: The sandbox you posted is breaking can you please fix it

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty Sorry about that! Fixed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are returning anonymous functions from `useSnackbar` hook, which creates a new function every time a re-render happens

Using `useCallback` on `showSnackbarVariant` function does the trick for me

Please find the updated `useSnackbar` hook below

**useSnackbar.js**

```
import { useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import { useSnackbar as useNotistackSnackbar } from "notistack";

const useSnackbar = () => {
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useNotistackSnackbar();

  const showSnackbarVariant = useCallback(
    ({ text, action_text, onActionClick, variant }) =>
      enqueueSnackbar(
        {
          variant,
          text,
          action_text,
          onActionClick
        },
        { autoHideDuration: action_text && onActionClick ? 9000 : 4000 }
      ),
    [enqueueSnackbar]
  );

  const showSuccessSnackbar = useCallback(
    ({ text, action_text, onActionClick }) => {
      showSnackbarVariant({
        variant: "success",
        text,
        action_text,
        onActionClick
      });
    },
    [showSnackbarVariant]
  );

  return {
    showSuccessSnackbar,
    showErrorSnackbar: ({ text, action_text, onActionClick }) => {
      console.log("eee");
      showSnackbarVariant({
        variant: "error",
        text,
        action_text,
        onActionClick
      });
    }
  };
};

export default useSnackbar;
```

Please find sandbox for reference:

[image: Edit gallant-wildflower-l5zy3]

Please Let me know if any explanation is needed

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much!

Comment: glad, that i can help

Answer (score 2):

you could save the result of your custom hook in a `useState` and then use this value in a useEffect to trigger your event at the right time.

```js
 const { showSuccessSnackbar, showErrorSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  const [isSuccess, setIsSuccess] = useState(false);
  const { mutate: activateConnectedAccount } = useCustomHook({
    onSuccess: async () => {
      showSuccessSnackbar({
        text: "Direct deposit has been enabled."
      });
      setIsSuccess(true);
    },
    onError: () => {
      showErrorSnackbar({
        text: "An error occurred. Please double check your bank information."
      });
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    activateConnectedAccount();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSuccess) {
      console.log("yooo");
    }
  }, [isSuccess]);
```

Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-tamas-1qmqi?file=/src/MyComponent.js)

Although I don't really understand why you would need to do this, as you could already do whatever needs to be done in your `onSuccess` callback. Your `useCustomHook` could also contain a `useEffect` within its body if you want it to hold the logic.

As the previous answer says if you use a function/complex object as a dependency on `useEffect` without `useCallback`/`useMemo`, the shallow comparison will fail and React will re-run the useEffect on every render.
If you pass primitive value, React is smart enough to re-run the `useEffect` only when that value changes.

I like to pass only primitive values as dependencies to avoid these issues of too many calls/ infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your showSuccessSnackbar in useCallback function and then pass it to useEffect.

```
const showSuccessSnackbarCallback = useCallback(() => {
    showSuccessSnackbar();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    activateConnectedAccount();
    console.log("yooo");
  }, [showSuccessSnackbarCallback]);
```